# Shuttil Python Copying Files onto Restricted Shared Drive

Tags: python, pdf

I am currently writing a program in python on a windows computer that uses selenium to download a pdf (using novaPDF) then rewrites that pdf with a new name.

However, the download and final saving location of this pdf is on a shared network drive.  I have access to the folders that are pertinent, and any user that would be utilizing this program would also have access to the correct folders.

With this being said, I am able to download the file perfectly (into the shared drive), but when I try to run `shutil.copy(curr, new)` to renamed the downloaded file to the proper name, I am getting `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`.  I realized I could move or renamed the file but I was getting similar issues, so I am currently copying then deleting the original (open to changing this).

I am thinking the issue is something with permissions on the shared drive, but it very well be something else.  I am going to keep working on this on my own, and will post if I get a solution, but feel free to ask any follow-up questions.  Help is always appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is `new` in a different directory? Then check the rights there. Any chance you accidentally named `curr` and `new` the same?

Comment: curr and new are not the same, because it works sometimes.  New is one directory deeper than curr.  Also, currently I have it running where if I get the error it waits a second then tries again.  That seems to be working

Comment: Sounds like the target exists and something has it open. You could try `os.path.exists` to debug.

Comment: @tdelaney prior to the accessing of the file I loop on `os.path.isfile`.  I tried with `os.path.exists` and that doesn't seem to work while the file is downloading

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer the question on a wide scale, but I'll provide some information in general that may help someone completing a similar project.

The trick seemed to be waiting until `os.path.isfile` returned true.  Then after that, wait a little longer.  What I did, is I ended up writing a helper function that takes the method and then calls it with a given number of retries.  This seemed  to work well, and it is incredibly useful in general for selenium as sometimes pages take a little longer to load than expected.

Here is the helper function:

```
    def helper_function(self, method, *args):
    '''
    This method is a wrapper to allow calls to retry if the original
    call fails
    :return: the element if any
    '''

    exception = None

    for i in xrange(config.number_of_retries):
        try:
            element = method(*args)
            return element
        except Exception as e:
            exception = e
    raise Exception("Number of retries exceeded: " + repr(exception))
```